# I have AWS SAM local 0.2.11 but I am not able to upgrade it to 0.3.0. Upgrade is not happening

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS.

```
/home/ashu# sam --version
A newer version of the AWS SAM CLI is available!
Your version:   0.2.11
Latest version: 0.3.0
See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local for upgrade instructions

sam version 0.2.11
```

But when i am trying to upgrade following the instruction [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli#upgrade-from-version-0-2-11-or-below)
I am not getting any succcess...

This command:
npm uninstall -g aws-sam-local

```
doesn't un-install the older version
```

and after this - the subsequent commands:

```
pip install --user --upgrade aws-sam-cli
```

is not upgrading it.

```
root@ashu-XPS-15-9560:~# pip install --user --upgrade aws-sam-cli
Requirement already up-to-date: aws-sam-cli in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six~=1.11.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: cookiecutter~=1.6.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: PyYAML~=3.12 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: enum34~=1.1.6 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: aws-sam-translator==1.5.4 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: click~=6.7 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: docker>=3.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: Flask~=0.12.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: boto3~=1.5 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: whichcraft>=0.4.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: binaryornot>=0.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: jinja2>=2.7 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=2.18.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: future>=0.15.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: poyo>=0.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: jinja2-time>=0.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: jsonschema~=2.6 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aws-sam-translator==1.5.4->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: backports.ssl-match-hostname>=3.5; python_version < "3.5" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: ipaddress>=1.0.16; python_version < "3.3" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: docker-pycreds>=0.2.3 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: websocket-client>=0.32.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: itsdangerous>=0.21 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask~=0.12.2->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: Werkzeug>=0.7 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask~=0.12.2->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from boto3~=1.5->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from boto3~=1.5->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.25 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from boto3~=1.5->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: chardet>=3.0.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from binaryornot>=0.2.0->cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jinja2>=2.7->cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests>=2.18.0->cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.0->cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.0->cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: arrow in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jinja2-time>=0.1.0->cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: functools32; python_version == "2.7" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jsonschema~=2.6->aws-sam-translator==1.5.4->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10->boto3~=1.5->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils>=0.10 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.25->boto3~=1.5->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.25->boto3~=1.5->aws-sam-cli)
Requirement already up-to-date: backports.functools-lru-cache>=1.2.1; python_version == "2.7" in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from arrow->jinja2-time>=0.1.0->cookiecutter~=1.6.0->aws-sam-cli)
root@ashu-XPS-15-9560:~# sam --version
A newer version of the AWS SAM CLI is available!
Your version:   0.2.11
Latest version: 0.3.0
See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local for upgrade instructions

sam version 0.2.11
```

Comment: I have this issue when attempting to upgrade from `0.2.11` to `0.4.0`. Any resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you are following the installation instructions [in the SAM documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/docs/installation.rst#upgrading)

It appears, however, that `npm` frequently fails to remove the sam executable. Run `which sam`, remove or move that file (e.g. `rm sam`), and restart your shell.  Then linux will find the correct `sam` on your PATH if you have followed the installation instructions.

(The root of the problem is, as you noted, an NPM issue, but that discussion is outside the scope of this question.)